# After changing window width, height changes automatically

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

When I am creating new window, I set its width and height manually and it is displayed correctly. However, If I try to change it after I call .show() method, it doesn't behave correctly. For example, if I change width, height changes automatically and vice versa.

SizeToContent property is set to Manual.

Comment: please add the xaml where you declare the window

Answer (score 1):

Please update your question providing xaml for both windows.
Because I can not comment yet... I shall try to provide you with the right answer using my project:
MainWindow.Xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="TestingHeightWidth.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestingHeightWidth"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="300" SizeToContent="Manual">
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="behaviorbtn" Content="Test" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="75" Click="behaviorbtn_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

New window's Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="TestingHeightWidth.testWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestingHeightWidth"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="testWindow" Height="300" Width="300" SizeToContent="Manual"> <!--Height and width values will be overwritten by the mainwindow's constructor-->
<Grid>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow's code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    testWindow testwnd = new testWindow();
    bool frstClick = true;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        testwnd.Height = 100; //before .Show();
        testwnd.Width = 200; 
        testwnd.Show();
    }

    private void behaviorbtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //After .Show();
        if (testwnd.Height == 400 && testwnd.Width == 500 && frstClick == false) //Second check
        {
            testwnd.Height = 100;
            testwnd.Width = 200;
        }
        if (testwnd.Visibility == Visibility.Visible && frstClick == true) //Runs first
        {
            testwnd.Height = 400;
            testwnd.Width = 500;
            frstClick = false;
        }

    }
}
```

This should lead you to the right way editing height and width properties. Good luck.